# How do I get the ID of the last push in git?

Tags: git

I'd like to get the ID for the last push received (not `git rev-parse HEAD`).

For example, if I do `git diff-tree --name-status master` it will show me all changes since the last push, but I want to see changes at a specific push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the last push that *you* (ie your repo) received from a given remote, for a given branch (like, for instance, master):

```
 git rev-parse origin/master
```

(this [blog post](http://www.freshblurbs.com/changes-last-push-git) illustrates it by listing changes since last push:
`git log origin/master.. --stat`

The command is also used in the question "[git erroneously states I'm ahead of origin/master by 1 commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087679/git-erroneously-states-im-ahead-of-origin-master-by-1-commit)")

Once you have the right SHA1, you can look at "[How can I see all the files that were modified/added/removed in the last push received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652435/how-can-i-see-all-the-files-that-were-modified-added-removed-in-the-last-push-re)" for more.

Comment: "How can I see all the files that were modified/added/removed in the last push received?" was your initial question, but illustrates diff-tree between two SHA1.

Comment: Thanks VonC. The thing is no editing is done on this repo. It only receives pushes. So, based on your answer I can get the ID at the last push (which is always HEAD) but what about the ID of the push before that? I'd need those two IDs so I can use diff-tree to see the differences.

Comment: @trusktr interesting. That would be the parent of  the last merge with `origin/master` and `master`.

Comment: I found a way to do it. I'm just using the post-receive hook which sends oldrev (old revision ID) and newrev (new revision ID) through stdin so I can do the comparison I need.