# git show last commits pushed

Tags: git

I'm updating my trello with the last commits pushed on the CI/CD pipeline. For the moment I'm using:

`git log --format='- %B' --no-merges HEAD^..HEAD`

But it's getting the last commit while I'd like to get a list of all the commits made since the last push.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the ID of the last push in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653318/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-the-last-push-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+commits+since+the+last+push

Answer (score 1):

So you'd have to change the reference against which you're comparing the present code.

Your range `HEAD^..HEAD` is a verbose way to designate `HEAD` which.... doesn't even need to be designated because it is implied when no ref is explicitly given.

So your command is equivalent to

```
git log --format='- %B' --no-merges --no-walk
```

---

But now for the need to compare against last pushed state : you'd have to use the remote state of the same branch.

Let's assume your branch is called `feature-1` and your remote `origin` :

```
# First let's make sure the remote ref is up-to-date
git fetch

# then the logging itself
git log --format='- %B' --no-merges origin/feature-1..feature-1
```

Comment: this should be done before the pull right? (I'm getting an empty list)

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot to mention! You'd have to `fetch` before you do your logging, to be sure you're comparing against a fresh reference. Editing now. (Don't `pull` instead of `fetch` or else your local and remote refs will be identical and you'll have nothing to compare left.)